# How to select and set value of column every nth row?

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

I have a df that looks like this:

```
   id
0  aaa
1  bbb
2  ccc
3  ddd
```

I want to create and set column 'win/lose', where every 3rd row starting at index 0 is equal to TRUE.

New df should look like this:

```
   id        win/lose
0  aaa        True
1  bbb        False
2  ccc        False
3  ddd        True
```

I can select every 3rd row like so:

```
df[df.index % 3 == 0]
```

I am at a lose as to how to set the column to TRUE for every third row, and every other row is FALSE.

I tried this a FOR loop, but I am not doing something correct.

```
for row in df.iterrows():
   df['Win'][df['Win'].index % 3 == 0] = 'TRUE'
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fastest way can be to directly check the index and assign it:

```
%time df['win/lose'] = df.index % 3 == 0                                                                                                                                                                                                                                  
CPU times: user 1.39 ms, sys: 71 µs, total: 1.47 ms
Wall time: 1.44 ms
```

You can also use apply to check the index, but this method is slower:

```
%time df['win/lose'] = df.apply(lambda x: x.index % 3 == 0)                                                                                                                                                                                                               
CPU times: user 3.48 ms, sys: 83 µs, total: 3.56 ms
Wall time: 3.5 ms
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try this.

```
df.assign(win_loss = df.index%3 == 0)

    id  win_loss
0  aaa      True
1  bbb     False
2  ccc     False
3  ddd      True
```